# Drawing a Linear Gradient in Quartz and turn it into a circle

Tags: macos, drawing, quartz-graphics

I want to draw a Linear Gradient and turn it into a circle, so that it looks like this at the end.
[image: linear gradient turned into a cricle]

Since this isn't a usual linear gradient, nor a real radial gradient, I do not have a real idea what to do and where to start.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.turnedondigital.com/blog/quartz-tutorial-how-to-draw-in-quartz/) is the exact example you are looking for. Download it source code and try it.

Comment: Good example for Quartz, but it doesn't use any Gradient.

Comment: Take a look again.  CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, 
         myGradient, 
         myStartPoint, myStartRadius, myEndPoint, myEndRadius, 0);